# Rails architecture issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I have a list of `Car`s.  I have a form above that can filter them based on different attributes. I wish to add filtering based on their model and sub-models.

Each car already has a `Manufacturer` and these have models and then sub-models.

How can I structure this in Rails?   Do I have a `Modell` and a `SubModell` (using those names to stop conflicting with rails own naming). or is there a better way?

I wish to be able to return the Manufacturer and Model and Sub Model directly from a car though. Like so:

```
c = Car.first
c.manufacturer # => "Ford"
c.model # => "Mondeo"
c.sub_model # => "Estate"
```

Is this possible?

Neil, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, the convention would be...

```
class VehicleManufacturer
  has_many vehicle_models
end

class VehicleModel
  has_many vehicle_sub_models
  belongs_to :vehicle_manufacturer
end

class VehicleSubModel
  belongs_to :vehicle_model
  has_many :vehicles
   delegate :vehicle_manufacturer, to: :vehicle_model
end

class Car
  belongs_to vehicle_sub_model
  delegate :vehicle_model, :vehicle_manufacturer, to: :vehicle_sub_model
  delegate :name, to: :vehicle_manufacturer, prefix: true
  delegate :name, to: :vehicle_model, prefix: true
  delegate :name, to: :vehicle_sub_model, prefix: true
end
```

This will let you do...

```
c = Car.first
c.vehicle_manufacturer_name # => "Ford"
c.vehicle_model_name # => "Mondeo"
c.vehicle_sub_model_name # => "Estate"
```

You would only need to assign the correct `vehicle_sub_model` to the `car` and the other classes would automatically be available.

In your case, you already have a `vehicle_manufacturer` association in the `car` model, so you don't need the delegation to `vehicle_manufacturer` in the model, but you would still need to assign the `vehicle_sub_model` to the car (otherwise you won't know what model / sub_model the car is)

Comment: Thanks for this.  What happens if I don't know the sub model OR the sub model and the model?    I still need to be able to get the manufacturer?

Comment: Then you'll have to specify a `belongs_to` association might be nil with `belongs_to : vehicle_model, optional: true`. Unless, you'll get an error on save of the record.

Comment: @brcebn Yes, but in the above code, the Car is not related to the manufacturer directly?   Surely if I have a car and need the manufacturer but do not have a model or sub-model then I cannot get the manufacturer?  This is what is confusing me

Comment: In this case, `VehicleManufacturer` has_many cars and there is another model matching a `VehicleManufacturer` and `VehicleModel`. 

Comment: @brcebn Ok, but according to the code above, the manufacturer and model are already associated?

Comment: I've added another possible solution. Let me know if you've any misunderstanding with it. 

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, very close to what Steve has proposed:

With this solution, a car might have several manufacturers without having a sub model linked (`optional: true`)

```rb
class VehicleManufacturer
  has_many :vehicle_models
  has_many :cars
end

class VehicleModel
  has_many :vehicle_sub_models
end

class VehicleSubModel
  belongs_to :vehicle_model
end

class Car
  # Limitation here, in case there is a "sub-sub-model" or if there is no "sub-model" but directly a model. 
  belongs_to :vehicle_model, optional: true
  has_one :vehicle_sub_model, through: :vehicle_model
  has_many :vehicle_manufacturers
  
  # Pay attention to the eager loading with delegation, it won't work. 
  delegate :vehicle_model, :vehicle_manufacturer, to: :vehicle_sub_model
  delegate :name, to: :vehicle_model, prefix: true
  delegate :name, to: :vehicle_sub_model, prefix: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but i'm getting really confused with it.  Your inline code comments are confusing me?   Also, what is :car_vehicle_manufacturers?   Is this a table i need to create, another model?  This surely should be easy but i'm having a really tricky time with it. I need this setup but need to ensure it allows adding Cars where I know the Manufacturer but not the Model or Sub Model.  By the way, a Car will only have one manufacturer

Comment: I also need this to allow having a manufacturer and model but NOT a sub model.  I know it's confusing.  I will get there, just feel i need more explanation. Thank you!